# openxml clonenode method cause data to shift column to the right in C#

Tags: c#, openxml

I am writing an application that grabs data from a database based on certain criteria and then exports it to an excel file. It works completely correctly till it gets to the last line of the excel file. Here is the code that writes the excel file:

```
    if (recordCounter == currentRecordList.Count() && previousRegionName == regionName)
            {
                rowInSheet1.Append(
                  excelController.ConstructCell(regionName, CellValues.String, 2), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(merchant, CellValues.String, 2),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFee.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 1),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 2),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.DateProcessed.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"), CellValues.String, 2),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(description, CellValues.String, 2)
                );
                sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);


                rowInSheet1.Append(
                  excelController.ConstructCell("TOTALS", CellValues.String, 6),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFeeAmount.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 6), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 6), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2)

                );
           
                sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1.CloneNode(false));
            }
            else if (recordCounter == currentRecordList.Count())
            {
                rowInSheet1.Append(
                  excelController.ConstructCell(regionName, CellValues.String, 2), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(merchant, CellValues.String, 2), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFee.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 1), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 2), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.DateProcessed.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"), CellValues.String, 2),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(description, CellValues.String, 2)
                );

                sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);

                rowInSheet1.Append(
                  excelController.ConstructCell("TOTALS", CellValues.String, 6), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFeeAmount.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 6), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 6), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2)

                );
                sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);
            }
            else
            {
                if ((previousCurrency == null && previousRegionName == null) || (previousCurrency == currentCurrency && previousRegionName == regionName))
                {
                    rowInSheet1.Append(
                      excelController.ConstructCell(regionName, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(merchant, CellValues.String, 2), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFee.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 1),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 2), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.DateProcessed.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"), CellValues.String, 2), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(description, CellValues.String, 2)
                    );
                    sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);
                    previousCurrency = currentCurrency;
                    previousTotal = currentTotal;
                    previousRegionName = regionName;

                }
                else
                {
                    rowInSheet1.Append(
                      excelController.ConstructCell("TOTALS", CellValues.String, 6), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(previousTotal.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 6),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(previousCurrency, CellValues.String, 6), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2)

                    );
                    sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);

                    Row emptyRow;
                    emptyRow = new Row();
                    emptyRow.Append(
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2)
                    );
                    sheetData1.Append(emptyRow);

                    Row row;
                    row = new Row();
                    row.Append(
                      excelController.ConstructCell(regionName, CellValues.String, 2), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(merchant, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFee.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 1), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 2), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.DateProcessed.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"), CellValues.String, 2), 
                      excelController.ConstructCell(description, CellValues.String, 2)
                    );
                    sheetData1.Append(row);

                    previousCurrency = currentCurrency;
                    previousTotal = currentTotal;
                    previousRegionName = regionName;
                }
                recordCounter++;
            }

        }
```

The clone node method is being used within the first if statement. I have it purposely set to false or else it just appends twice at the end of the excel file.

This is my expected result:

[image]

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

I have tried using the Remove method but that does not seem to work either.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by just instantiating a different row

```
            rowInSheet1 = new Row();
            firstRow = new Row();

            if (recordCounter == currentRecordList.Count() && previousRegionName == regionName)
            {
                firstRow.Append(
                  excelController.ConstructCell(regionName, CellValues.String, 2), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(merchant, CellValues.String, 2),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFee.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 1),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 2),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.DateProcessed.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"), CellValues.String, 2),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(description, CellValues.String, 2)
                );
                sheetData1.Append(firstRow);


                rowInSheet1.Append(
                  excelController.ConstructCell("TOTALS", CellValues.String, 6),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFeeAmount.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 6), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 6), 
                  excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                  excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2)

                );
                sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);
                //sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1.CloneNode(false));
            }
```

I used this firstRow instead of using the clonenode method. Worked like a charm!